# Django Regex Validator Not Working - Error 500 Deployment Server

Tags: python, django, regex

Take the following example:

```py
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    client = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Client Name (lowercase)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-z]+$', 'Enter a valid client name (only lowercase letters)')])
    stage = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)
    folder = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FOLDERS, required=False, label='')
    purpose = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Project Purpose (lowercase; digit optional)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-z-]+[1-9]?$', 'Enter a valid purpose (only lowercase letters, with a single optional digit)')])
    computeapi = forms.BooleanField(required=True, initial=True, label='Compute Engine')
    deploymentmanapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Deployment Manager')
    storagecompapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Storage Components')
    monitorapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Monitoring')
    loggingapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Logging')

    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
        projectname = form_data['client'] + "-" + form_data['stage'] + "-" + form_data['purpose']
        client = form_data['client']
        purpose = form_data['purpose']
        for projectdict in projectdicts:
            if projectname == projectdict['name']:
                raise ValidationError(projectname + " already exists! Please try another name.")
        
        if not re.match("^[a-z-]+[1-9]?$", purpose):
            raise ValidationError(purpose + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
        
        if not re.match("^[a-z]+$", client):
            raise ValidationError(client + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
        return form_data
```

The ValidationError for projectname works perfectly fine as expected.
However, it's not working for Regex, and instead keeps throwing a 500 error.
Is there something we need to do specifically to get the RegexValidator to work as expected within the class variables? I don't believe my additional code in the clean is needed (and if it is, it's not working as it should).

Any help with this would be appreciated.

**Edit 28/08/2020:**
**Traceback, as requested:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Company\GCP App Engine\Test-Django-Terraform-Deployments - Copy\webscripts\views.py", line 30, in projectcreation
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 382, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 409, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Company\GCP App Engine\Test-Django-Terraform-Deployments - Copy\webscripts\projectform.py", line 90, in clean
    projectname = form_data['client'] + "-" + form_data['stage'] + "-" + form_data['purpose']
KeyError: 'client'
```

The projectdicts dictionary is a global variable generated from a GET request to Google Cloud to generate a list of names of all projects:

```
try:
    global projectdicts
    projectdicts = cloudresmanv1.projects().list().execute()
    projectdicts = projectdicts.get('projects')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

Comment: where from did you get projectdicts variable in clean, post an error trackback which you can get from log

Comment: @iklinac - I've updated the original post with the error message. It's just a simple KeyError.
The projectdicts dictionary is a global variable generated from a GET request to Google Cloud to generate a list of names of all projects.

Comment: using global variables is not a good idea and it is considered anti-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the traceback you've provided;

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 409, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Company\GCP App Engine\Test-Django-Terraform-Deployments - Copy\webscripts\projectform.py", line 90, in clean
    projectname = form_data['client'] + "-" + form_data['stage'] + "-" + form_data['purpose']
KeyError: 'client'
```

The `form_data` hasn't got a value for `client` so it's not present in the dictionary. So it's failing when setting `projectname` and never reaching your regex validators.

You need to be more defensive in your validation to ensure that data exists before trying to use it. By which I mean do something like this;

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        data_invalid = False

        # Setting required attrs on the fields should ensure the browser 
        # enforces validation, but this will double check before you cause a server error

        for field in (
                'client',
                'purpose',
                'stage',
        ):
            if not cleaned_data.get(field):
                self.add_error(field, 'This field is required')
                data_invalid = True

        if data_invalid:
            # Return early because data is missing
            return cleaned_data


        client = cleaned_data.get('client')
        purpose = cleaned_data.get('purpose')
        stage = cleaned_data.get('stage')

        # Once you know the data is there, you can then go on to use it &
        # add your validators
        
        if client and purpose and stage:
            projectname = client + "-" + stage + "-" + purpose
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling clean of super class so your form.clean_data is empty

```
def clean(self):
    form_data = super(ProjectForm, self).clean()
    projectname = form_data['client'] + "-" + form_data['stage'] + "-" + form_data['purpose']
    client = form_data['client']
    purpose = form_data['purpose']
    for projectdict in projectdicts:
        if projectname == projectdict['name']:
            raise ValidationError(projectname + " already exists! Please try another name.")
    
    if not re.match("^[a-z-]+[1-9]?$", purpose):
        raise ValidationError(purpose + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
    
    if not re.match("^[a-z]+$", client):
        raise ValidationError(client + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
    return form_data
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still giving the same 500 error.